# Generate N Records

Tags: postgresql

Is there a faster way to do something like this? Maybe using `generate_series`?

```
INSERT INTO users (email)
VALUES
  ('user1@domain.com'),
  ('user2@domain.com'),
  ('user3@domain.com')
```

Is it possible to also easily add a relation for a profile?

```
INSERT INTO profiles (user_id)
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='user1@domain.com'

INSERT INTO profiles (user_id)
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='user2@domain.com'

INSERT INTO profiles (user_id)
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='user3@domain.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT generate_series(1, 3, 1) AS num
)

INSERT INTO users (email)
SELECT 'user' || num::text || '@domain.com'
FROM cte;
```

Modify the second parameter to `generate_series` if you want to generate more than 3 user emails.

**Edit:** For your updated requirement:

```sql
WITH emails AS (
    SELECT 'user' || generate_series(1, 3) || '@domain.com' AS email
)

INSERT INTO profiles (user_id)
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM emails);
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to also add a record to a relation such as a profile? For example, add a profiles record for each new user with a foreign key profiles.user_id?

Comment: @Dex I'm not sure I follow what else you want.  You may edit your question if the change be relatively minor (and otherwise, please just ask a new question).

Comment: Try that otherwise I'll create a new question

Comment: I have given you a query for the updated requriement.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO users
SELECT 'user' || generate_series(1, 10) || '@domain.com'
```

[generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-srf.html)(1, 10) - This generates a series of 1 to 10 rows

---

As per the updated requirement,

```
INSERT INTO profiles (user_id)
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE email in
    (SELECT 'user' || generate_series(1, 10) || '@domain.com')
```